# No visible @interface for 'ImageEditorViewController' declares the selector 'initWithImageAndSaveName:saveName:'

Tags: iphone, xcode

I have been messing with this For days . I am new to xcode.. but just dont Get why I keep getting this error. I have tried and tried ... im hoping that someone can help me out. thank you for your time

```
- (void)longPressAction:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    CGPoint touchLocation = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.webView];

    NSString *javascript = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.elementFromPoint(%f, %f).src", touchLocation.x, touchLocation.y];
    NSString *imageUrl = [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:javascript];

    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageUrl]];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

    // Show the editor
    ImageEditorViewController *editView = [[ImageEditorViewController alloc] initWithImageAndSaveName:image saveName:[imageUrl lastPathComponent]];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:editView animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Where do you declare and implement these methods? Do cmd-shift-f to search entire project.

Answer (score 1):

Look in the .h file for "`ImageEditorViewController`" and see if it has a method declaration in there for "`initWithImageAndSaveName:saveName:'`".

Also make sure the ImageEditorViewController.h file is imported into the .m file that contains your "`longPressAction`" method.

Answer (score 0):

It is simply trying to tell you that there is no method that exists with that name.  There are two places where you could write that method.  One would be in the header file between @interface and @end.  The other location would be to put it in-between the @implementation and @end part of the .m file.  I would recommend the latter, unless you are planning on subclassing this class and having another class use the method.  It's just a little cleaner to only declare it in the @implementation and then privately reference it in your own methods.

Basically, though, to keep it short and simple, that method does not currently exist, and you need to implement it if you want to use it.

Comment: Although if it is not in the header, it would not be visible from the class where he is trying to call it from. He probably has it in the .m already, just doesn't have it in the header.

Comment: Yeah I assumed he was calling it from within the ImageEditViewController class itself.  If he is importing the ImageEditViewController and doing his customer initialization from that then he should definitely have it in the .h.

Comment: Would it help if i posted the Full codes for them two Files ? I cant express how close i am to Pulling my hair out LOL. I have been trying this for days, after my Dev quit out of no where on me leaving me with 99% Finished app. I would be more then glad to give remote into My mac if someone would be kind enough to help me.

Comment: How about you first post code for the .h file?  And that sounds like a really awful situation to be in.

Comment: Yeah it really is to be honest... I was able to get it working With the help of a good friend. I have found a new team of devs as well thank god!

This is my first post here. but I have to say I think im going to like this place. some really nice and helpful people. Along with great information when venturing into the Coding world ha 

Thanks again guys 

If anyone here has a JB device I would like to give you free copies or our apps in Cydia 

ManChildTechnologies.com